# Use AppActivate to change the active window

Tags: vbscript

I'm am trying to send some keystrokes to a program. I have some example code below which works fine up until the final `{Alt}` command. I believe this is due to the window name changing from `"Notepad1"` to `"NotePad2"`. Could anyone help me change the `AppActivate` path to `"Notepad2"` after the `objShell.SendKeys "{Enter}"` command?

Example:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "Notepad.exe"
Do Until Success = True
Success = objShell.AppActivate("NotepadPathA")
Loop
objShell.SendKeys "{F1}"
objShell.SendKeys "Secure06**"
objShell.SendKeys "{Enter}"
Shell.SendKeys "{Alt}"
```

Answer (score 4):

1. You're using `Shell` on your last line but you haven't defined it. Change it to `objShell` instead.
2. To send the `Alt` key, use `"%"`. For example:

   ```
   objShell.SendKeys "%"
   ```

   You would typically use this in a key combination. For example, to open the `File` menu in most programs, you would use `Alt`+`F`, or:

   ```
   objShell.SendKeys "%f"
   ```
3. If your window title changes, or you need to activate a new window for whatever reason, just call `AppActivate` again:

   ```
   objShell.AppActivate "My new window title"
   ```

Comment: If this solved your issue, consider [accepting it as answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Each windows process has an identifier.  If you store the process id for each notepad window, you can avoid worrying about finding the right window after its title changes.

Here is an example of opening two notepad files, activating by process id and sending keys.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Function SendKeysTo (process, keys, wait)
    objShell.AppActivate(process.ProcessID)
    objShell.SendKeys keys
    WScript.Sleep wait
End Function

Set notepadA= objShell.Exec("notepad")
Set notepadB= objShell.Exec("notepad")
WScript.Sleep 500


SendKeysTo notepadA, "Hello I am Notepad A", 1000
SendKeysTo notepadB, "Hello I am Notepad B", 1000
```

Hopefully you can take a similar approach to solve your problem.

Comment: No I dont think so, ive just changed that objShell.SendKeys "{Alt}" but i get the same error Line 9 , Char 1, Error "Invalid Procedure call or argument" Code: 800A005, Source MS VBScript runtime error. I believe the error is because after the {Enter} command the window changes name so i need to somehow reference that window instead.

Comment: I've edited the answer to accommodate changing window titles.